# Why is SQLAlchemy so slow when dealing with many results?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm having a problem with the performance of my SQLAlchemy application, and I've noticed that queries are slow even when they are pretty much as simple as they could be:

```py
data = [x[0] for x in db.query(MyTable.id).all()]
# takes ~30 ms after being warmed up, 4500 results
```

Using raw queries isn't better:

```py
raw = [x[0] for x in db.execute("SELECT id FROM mytable").all()]
# takes ~30 ms after warmup, same results
```

But I've discovered that aggregating the query to JSON on the DB side, then parsing the JSON on the client is pretty fast:

```py
raw_json = json.loads(db.execute("SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(id) FROM mytable").scalar_one())
# takes ~3ms, same results again
```

This is consistent with the timings I'm getting when using other clients to issue the original SQL statement, but it's very verbose to write my queries like this.

So, my question is:

1. ~~Why is the second approach three times faster than the first one? They are generating the same query. The x3 overhead seems to scale with the amount of data.~~ **EDIT:** that was a mistake in my testing setup
2. Why is the third approach ten times faster than the second one? Is there a more efficient method of getting results out of a query other than `db.execute(...).all()`? (`.scalars().all()` does not seem to make a difference.)

I'm on SQLAlchemy 1.4 with pymysql 1.0.2 and Python 3.10 right now, but could probably switch.

Comment: SQLAchemy is designed for convenience, not maximum performance.  If the difference between a 30ms query and a 90ms query is important to you, then you should not use an object relational mapper at all.  Use SQL directly.

Comment: The overhead is at least in part down to other factors: I get better results using mysql-connector-python rather than pymysql, and writing to postgres using psycopg2 is about twice as fast.

Comment: Sorry, looks like the difference between the first and the second example was due to a peculiarity of my testing setup. I've updated the post.

> "Use SQL directly."
-- Isn't this what I'm doing in the second example?

Answer (score 1):

It takes time to send 4500 rows to the client -- parse query, run Optimizer, fetch, serialize, send through the network, collect rows, and unserialize.  Each step is done 4500 times.

Sending one row, even if it took 4500 rows to build that one row, avoids much of the overhead.

(For further discussion, please provide the *generated* SQL and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There are many other possible issues.)

Comment: What? The query is parsed and optimized once per row? And how does that explain the difference between SQLAlchemy/pymysql and using a different client?

Comment: This is why you should try to handle all 4500 rows in a _single_ SQL statement.  I have no clue whether SQLAlchemy is creating 1 big query or 4500 single-row queries.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. But my second example definitely uses a single query and is just as slow as the first.